# Can we prove that $2^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {x \choose k} =1, x \in R^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Inspired by today's post in MSE:

[A sum of absolute values of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810399/a-sum-of-absolute-values-of-binomial-coefficients)

my numerical experiments at Mathematica throw up:
$$2^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {x \choose k} =1, x\in R^{+},$$
fairly accurately.
When $x$ is positive integer it is the well known identity. However for real positive values
it is surprising ! Even if $x$ is non-real such that $\Re(x) >0$, it seems to hold fairly accurately.
Any comment, Reference of proof is welcome.

Comment: This is just the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) $(1+t)^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{x}{k}t^k$ with $t\to 1^-$ justified by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem); all you need is to establish the convergence, which is fairly easy.

Comment: Appears asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708686/can-we-calculate-2k-using-this-easy-taylor-series).